# Auto scaled worker/daemon as Kafka consumer

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We are planning to have a Kafka consumer in Java as a daemon, which needs to sniff Kafka for messages but would like to know how we can autoscale this daemon(s). Please suggest a best design for this

Going through this AWS worker, is that a good solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are talking about EBS Worker environment. EBS worker environment works on SQS will not help in case of kafka.

For consumers defined for kafka queues, you will need to define custom autoscaling strategy. Apart from out of the box scaling driven by ec2 metrics,cloudwatch and ASGs, you may have to publish further metrics to cloudwatch which will allow you to define triggers for autoscaling. With cloudwatch alerts you can configure backing lambda functions which can do the autoscaling.
Of course the above just a simplified way for implementing scaling, you can implement something which works for your environment.

Queue length(message consumption rate) is a good metric to consider for scaling, you should provisions to scale on queue length. This should be additional to scaling based on CPU,IO and other criteria.

Comment: If not Ebs worker is there any Kafka consumer where I can implement autoscaling ...please suggest

Comment: No..you will have to build ur own

Comment: Ok you mean cloudwatch triggers a lambda function to spin up ec2 instances based on metrics like cpu or other metrics ??? Don't we need any autoscaling group??

Comment: I guess we don't need any lambda we can just have autoscaling group defined in ec2 cloud formation based on cpu or other metrics ,correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: If you only want to scale instance level, configuring scaling at the ASG level based on available metrics should work.

Comment: Trying to understand wat do you mean by only at instance level ..anyway Kafka consumer will be deployed in ec2 right ...wat else needs to be auto scaled?

Comment: some cases people want to scale at process level, or container level(with docker), in those cases ASG scaling may not be appropriate. You may have to write custom lambda scripting.

Comment: We are not using docker anyway ..when you say process level can I relate to a Kafka consumer running in ec2... I.e. Scaling consumer within an ec2 instance??

Comment: Yes. In some cases it is appropriate to just scale the process(Add more processes).. but one process per instance is a good model for scaling. And would not need you to build a lot of logic for scaling.

Comment: Ok lemme summarize need to create a Java daemon application (which sniffs Kafka pipe ) and deploy in an ec2 instance which has ASG set ?

Comment: By sniff, you mean consume? Yes define an ASG, and deploy the app using  either userdata or a custom AMI. The process should automatically start at instance startup, so that autoscaling can work correctly.

Comment: Yeah continuously sniff Kafka pipe and consume messages ..that should be possible right ?

Comment: Yes. You should be able to do that

Comment: Cool thanks !!! Please lemme know if you have any sample Kafka consumer in Java with proper error handling and security..